# Can this form of reflection be consistent?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

> Is this form of reflection consistent?

First I'll begin by clarifying the notation I'm using here:

By a quantifier being relativized or bounded it means that the first occurrence of the quantified variable must be followed by $\in $ or $\subseteq$ symbols, followed by a variable symbol, like: $\forall x \in v; \exists x \in k; \forall x \subseteq v; \exists y \subseteq k$.

For any formula $\varphi$ that doesn't use the symbol "$W$" let $\varphi^{``W}$ denote any formula that is obtained by *merely* relativizing ***some*** of the quantifiers in $\varphi$ by "$\in W$" in such a manner that any quantifier so relativized to $W$ must have all *preceding* quantifiers appear bounded. To be worned is that no quantifier in $\varphi^{``W}$ can be newely bounded by other than "$\in W$", and so all quantifiers in $\varphi^{``W}$ preceding a quantifier  relativized to $W$ that are not bounded by $W$ must appear as bounded originally in $\varphi$ and so retain their original bounds in $\varphi$.

Examples: Let $\varphi$ be the formula $(\forall a \subseteq A \exists y: y=a)$
, and $\varphi^{``W}$ be the formula $(\forall a \subseteq A \exists y \in W: y=a)$; however we can also have $\varphi^{``W}$ be the formula $(\forall a \in W (a \subseteq A \to  \exists y \in W: y =a ))$. Another example is let $\varphi$ be the formula $(\forall a \in A \forall y \in a \exists z: z=y) $, and $\varphi^{``W}$ being the formula $(\forall a \in A \forall y \in a \exists z \in W: z=y)$, but also we can have $\varphi^{``W}$ be the formula $(\forall a \in W (a \in A \to \forall y \in W (y \in a \to \exists z \in W: z=y)))$

**Reflection$^*$:** $\forall \vec{v} \exists W \, (\varphi \to \varphi^{``W})$

I highly suspect that this scheme is inconsistent. Hence the question.

The point is that if we allow quantifiers in $\varphi^{``W}$ prior to those bounded by $W$ to be unbounded, then this straightforwardly enacts a paradox, simply take $\varphi$ to be $\forall x \exists y : y =x$ and $\varphi^{``W}$ to be $\forall x \exists y \in W: y=x$, then $W$ would be the universal set.

Of note is that if it turns to be consistent, then it together with Extensionality and Separation would prove all axioms of $\sf ZF-Reg.$. Also, it would directly prove Collection without resorting to any of the axioms of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: You are using the symbol $V$, which usually has a special meaning in set theory as the class of all sets, but it seems that you are not using it this way?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, $V$ here is just a parameter. It doesn't specifically denote any set.

Comment: You should use $v$ then, or another letter, since $V$ already means something else in set theory contexts.

Comment: The notation $\varphi^X$ is standard notation for bounding all quantifiers in $\varphi$ by $X$. You have your own private meaning for this notation, however, and it may be best to warn the readers.

Comment: Since for some formulas $\varphi$ there is not one unique formula that is $\varphi^{` ` W}$, which formulas $\varphi^{` ` W}$ are chosen for use in the schema Reflection*?

Comment: @C7X, all of them, it is a schema, you have an instance for each one of them!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit, Mar 3:** After some discussion with Zuhair Al-Johar, the full answer (that $\mathrm{Reflection}^*$ is a theorem schema of $\mathrm{ZFC}$) appears in the last line of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/465962) answer.

Here is a partial answer. If only one open (necessarily the leftmost that is open) quantifier bounded to $W$ is allowed in $\varphi^{``W}$, then this schema is consistent relative to an inaccessible cardinal.

---

Let $\mathscr L_\in$ be the first-order language with relation symbol $\in$, and without quantifiers $\forall x \subseteq v$ or $\exists y \subseteq k$. Let $\mathscr L_{\subseteq}$ be the first-order language with relation symbol $\in$ and bounded quantifiers $\forall x \subseteq v$ and $\exists y \subseteq k$. Let $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\in,1}$ be the schema $\mathsf{Reflection}^*$, but only considering $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{``W}$ that are $\mathscr L_\in$ formulae, and only allowing one open (necessarily the outermost open) quantifier in $\varphi^{``W}$ to be bounded by $W$. Define $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\mathcal P,1}$ similarly except using the language $\mathcal L_{\mathcal P}$ that is yet to be defined.

It follows from lemma 6.1 on p.57 of Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite* that if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then there is an unbounded set of $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha\prec V_\kappa$. For any finite subset $\vec v$ of $V_\kappa$, as the ranks of sets in $\vec v$ must be bounded below $\kappa$, there is a $V_\alpha\prec V_\kappa$ such that $\vec v\subset V_\alpha$. (Call this property the "substructure property of $\kappa$".)

**Theorem 1:** Assume $\kappa$ is inaccessible. Then $V_\kappa$ satisfies the $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\in,1}$.

**Proof:** Let $Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$ be an arbitrary $\mathscr L_\in$ formula in which $W$ does not appear, where each $Q_i(y_i\in b_i)$ is a bounded quantifier and $\vec y$ is $y_0,\ldots,y_k$, and choose a sequence of parameters $\vec v\in V_\kappa$. By the substructure property of $\kappa$, choose an $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $V_\alpha\prec V_\kappa$, $b_0,\ldots,b_k\in V_\alpha$, and $\vec v\in V_\alpha$, this $V_\alpha$ will serve as $W$ from here. It is sufficient to show that if $V_\kappa\vDash Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\forall x\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$ then $V_\kappa\vDash Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\forall(x\in W)\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$, and if $V_\kappa\vDash Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\exists x\psi(x,\vec v)$ then $V_\kappa\vDash Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\exists(x\in W)\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$. As any given $\varphi^{``W}$ must be in either of these latter forms, then $V_\kappa\vDash\varphi$ will imply $V_\kappa\vDash\varphi^{``W}$ as desired.

Universal quantifier case: Assume that $V_\kappa\vDash Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\forall x\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$. As the leading nodded quantifies are absolute between $V_\kappa$ and $W$, we can continue by choosing arbitrary values of $y_i$, $0\leq i\leq k$, that witness the satisfaction. Then $V_\kappa\vDash\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$ holds for arbitrary parameter $x\in V_\kappa$, so if we choose arbitrary $x\in W$, $V_\kappa\vDash\psi(x,\vec v)$ holds. As $x\in W$ was arbitrary, we have that $\forall(x\in W)(V_\kappa\vDash\psi(x,\vec v)$, so $V_\kappa\vDash\forall(x\in W)\psi(x,\vec v)$. We can then recover the leading bounded quantifiers.

Existential quantifier case: Assume that $V_\kappa\vDash q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots Q_k(y_k\in b_k)\exists x\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$. Again, the leading bounded quantifiers are absolute, so choose arbitrary $\vec y$ witnessing the satisfaction. By elementarity, $W\vDash\exists x\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$ as well. Choose a witnessing $x\in W$. We have $W\vDash\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$, and by elementarity again, $V_\kappa\vDash\psi(x,\vec y,\vec v)$. As $x$ was chosen from $W$, we have $V_\kappa\vDash\exists(x\in W)\psi(x,\vec v)$. The leading bounded quantifiers can then be recovered. $\square$

So $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\in,1}$ is consistent, assuming an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ exists. But how do we deal with bounded quantifiers $\forall x \subseteq v$ and $\exists y \subseteq k$?

Let $\mathscr L_{\mathcal P}$ be the first-order language with relation symbol $\in$ and a function symbol $\mathcal P$, to be interpreted as powerset. In particular $\mathscr L_{\mathcal P}$ does not have the bounded quantifiers $\forall x \subseteq v$ and $\exists y \subseteq k$. There is a translation from $\mathscr L_\subseteq$ to $\mathscr L_{\mathcal P}$ by replacing $\forall(x\subseteq v)(\ldots)$ with $\forall x(x\in\mathcal P(v)\implies\ldots)$ and $\exists(y\subseteq k)(\ldots)$ with $\exists y(y\in\mathcal P(k)\implies\ldots)$.

In fact, in *The Higher Infinite* (lemma 6.1, p.57) there is a superficially stronger version of the susbtructure property of inaccessible cardinals, which allows class parameters: For any $R\subseteq V_\kappa$, the set of $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $(V_\alpha,\in,R\cap V_\alpha)\prec(V_\kappa,\in,R)$ is closed and unbounded in $\kappa$. Then we get the following strengthening of theorem 1, giving a partial answer, at least when only one quantifier bounded to $W$ appears in $\varphi{``W}$.

**Theorem 2:** Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal. Then $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\mathcal P,1}$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

**Proof:** Similarly to the proof of theorem 1, let $\vec Q\psi(x,\vec v)$ be an arbitrary $\mathscr L_\in$ formula in which $W$ does not appear, where $\vec Q$ is an abbreviation of the part $Q_0(y_0\in b_0)\ldots q_k(y_k\in b_k)$ as appearing before, and choose a sequence of parameters $\vec v\in V_\kappa$. Now choose an $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $(V_\alpha,\in,\mathcal P\upharpoonright V_\alpha)\prec(V_\kappa,\in,\mathcal P\upharpoonright V_\kappa)$ and $\vec v\in V_\alpha$, this $V_\alpha$ will serve as $W$. Repeat the rest of the proof of theorem 1.

This shows $V_\kappa\vDash\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\mathcal P,1}$. As $\kappa$ is inaccessible, $V_\kappa$ is also a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, therefore $\mathsf{Reflection}^*_{\mathcal P,1}$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$. $\square$

---

My naive attempt to try and allow more than one quantifier bounded by $W$ by removing the "in which $W$ does not appear" condition from $\psi$ in theorem 1 did not work: the proof relies on $W$ being an unused symbol so that an interpretation $V_\alpha$ of it can be chosen. It would also over-proves, as it would prove that $V_\kappa$ models this stronger schema when in actuality it is inconsistent, for example if $\varphi$ is $\exists x\forall(y\in W)(x\in y)$ and $\varphi^{``W}$ is $\exists(x\in W)\forall(y\in W)(x\in y)$.

Comment: Regarding your last line, there is a breach of the order of bounding by $W$ that this method bestows on quantifiers, you left $x$ open before a variable that is bounded by $W$, that breaches anterior closure of bounding by $W$. Of course, this brews all kinds of inconsistency.

Comment: For the language $\mathscr L_{\mathcal P}$ is $\mathcal P$ is class symbol or a set symbol. I mean if you are using the version allowing class symbols, then we can take it to be a class symbol. The idea is to prove power set axiom from the scheme.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Re. 1st comment: You're right, when reading I must have thought that anterior closure meant that the block of quantifiers that get newly bounded to $W$ has to be anterior-closed.

Comment: Re. 3rd comment: If I have done it correctly, the point of introducing the class symbol should be to show there is a model $V_\kappa$ in which every formula, including ones in the language which uses quantifiers like $\forall x\subseteq k$, will anterior-reflect, as long as only one quantifier gets bounded to $W$. This model existence shows it is consistent with ZFC, but $\mathcal P$ need not be a function symbol in any model where anterior-reflection with 1 bounded quantifier is considered.

Comment: What I'm trying to say regarding my first comment is that the $x$ symbol in your example must either appear as bounded in $\varphi$ (not necessarily by $W$, i.e. it can be $\in k$ or $\subseteq k$ bounded for example where $k$ is some parameter). If the quantifier over $x$ is open in $\varphi$ then the next quantified variable $y$ must not appear bound to $W$ since this breaches anterior bounding of quantifiers by $W$.

Comment: I wonder if [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464825/95347) by Hamkins can be incorporated somehow here to show that we can have more than one quantifier bounded by $W$.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You are correct, anterior-closedness of the bounded quantifiers is violated. This happens since the "$W$ does not occur" clause was removed, breaching the order of the bounding and making the $\varphi^{``W}$ considered diverge from how the order of bounding works in Reflection*. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Hamkins's proof is a good starting point, and it seems to bound the quantifiers "all at once" rather than inductively adding them. It may work to simply use the fact that $\mathcal P$ never shows up in the block of bounded quantifiers, so the subformula of $\varphi$ in which all the $\mathcal P$'s appear is still absolute to $V_\kappa$ by $(V_\alpha,\in,\mathcal P\upharpoonright V_\alpha)\prec(V_\kappa,\in,\mathcal P\upharpoonright V_\kappa)$, but I am less comfortable working with arguments that "bound all the quantifiers at once" as I am not sure if a mistake would slip in.

Comment: How I'm reading your proof, your $\varphi^{"W}$ formulas are only those that have their outermost (i.e. the first variable from the left) being bounded by $W$, so there is no initial segment of bounded variables (both in $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{"W}$) before that. Is that correct? If that is the case then Hamkins proof already proves that. If that is true, then we cannot prove union, power, replacement, collection, since those depend on having an initial originally bounded segment before the first $W$ bounded quantifier!

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar "Is that correct?" - That is correct. In your most recent comment I am reading "before that" as meaning "rightwards of that". "then Hamkins proof already proves that" - the main way I understand this is that it would happen if the expansion of the language by $\mathcal P$ is unnecessary, and everything can be kept in $\mathscr L_\in$ by simply replacing $\forall x\subseteq k\ldots$ with $\exists K(\forall y(y\subseteq k\iff y\in K)\land\ldots)$, etc. Is this also your line of reasoning? (Soon it may be a good idea to move to chat from this thread.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151682/discussion-between-zuhair-al-johar-and-c7x).